# What is the bit?

Tags: bit

Everyone says that bit is the smallest **unit of information**.
But I don't understand what that **unit of information** means.
Is bit the smallest **capacity** of information?
Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: First result from google:
A bit (short for binary digit) is the smallest unit of data in a computer. A bit has a single binary value, either 0 or 1. Although computers usually provide instructions that can test and manipulate bits, they generally are designed to store data and execute instructions in bit multiples called bytes.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Units_of_information

Comment: That's not what I'm curious about. I'm curious about what means "UNIT OF DATA".

Comment: I already saw that wiki before question.. but i can’t explicitly understand it so i quest about this…

Comment: the same problem, FYI:
What is the full meaning of unit?
unit of measurement, unit(noun) any division of quantity accepted as a standard of measurement or exchange.
Bit is iternationally accepted unit of information, can be 0/1 which can mean a single number or a truth value. Adding more bits (units of information) together, you can achieve more complex information, such as numbers, letters, words, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The "unit of information" is the way we can present data, in this case it's in a digital form.

For example, base 10 (1, 2, 3 ... 9) is a unit of information. It's the way that we can present data with loads of different states. We can present the number 100 using base 10, the number 0xFF using base 16, we can even represent data using physical measurements like kilograms or grams, or megabytes and gigabytes.

These are just examples, but the main point is that a unit of information is just the way we can represent data.

The "smallest" representation we can have is a bit, because you only have 2 states: `1` and `0`. And that's pretty much it.